# Authentication of background tasks using Spring Boot and Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot, project-reactor

I have a background task (running with Project Reactor, but I don't think it is relevant) that I need to run in with an authenticated user to get through some @PreAuthorize annotated methods.

I'm doing something like this:

```
Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(login, password));
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
```

But when I trace into the authenticationManager call, I find that it is using Spring-Boot's default InMemoryUserDetailsService, rather than my custom authentication configuration. This happens regardless of whether I run the authentication in a web request thread, or in the background thread.

I don't know if it is relevant, but I am running this code in an integration test, with these annotations (among others):

```
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes=MyAppConfiguration.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@IntegrationTest({"server.port:0"})
```

In addition to this problem, my test makes an authenticated web request to my server, and that authenticates just fine. So I know at least the web portion of my system is using the correct authenication configuration.

Here is my authentication configuration:

```
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(jsr250Enabled=true, prePostEnabled=true)
public abstract class BaseSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public LocalUserDetailsService localUserDetailsService;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(localUserDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().httpBasic()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers( "/admin/**" ).hasRole( "ADMIN" )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to tell without your test implementatiton but it matters that you are running it in integration test
Maybe you are forgetting to add   `FilterChainProxy to your mockMvc

like this `mvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context)
                .addFilter(springSecurityFilterChain).build();`

instance of filterChainPrioxy can be @Autowired into your test class, of course this answer may not make sense, depends of your implementation of test class

---after your comment

this line :

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
```

assigns security constrains to current thread and does not impact threads running in background, unless your strategy is global and it is not default

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. This doesn't help for two reasons: 1) I'm not using `MockMvc`, I'm running the actual server and making real Http calls using Spring's `HttpEntity` API. 2) The actual http request works fine and authenticates correctly. It is a background thread that is getting the wrong authentication configuration, or possibly the entire wrong Spring context?

Comment: I do not think you are dealing here with spring context per se rather SecurityContext, that asigns security constrains to present thread, if there is another thread in background it has its own securityContext, thus operates on different set of constrains

Comment: so you would have to access SecurityContextHolder within that thread and attempt your modifications, or use maybe GlobalSecurityContextHolderStrategy that assigns security strategy globally if it is only for testing